# cannot add parentContext to NSManagedObjectContext, context already has a coordinator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a view where I retrieve a saved Entity (Route *) from the main `NSManagedObjectContext`.  I want to import that into a `tempContext`.  Following Marcus Zarra's examples, I do this:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = _route.managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObjectID *routeId = [_route objectID];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = moc.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    self.tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.tempContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
    NSManagedObject *localRoute = [self.tempContext objectWithID:routeId];
    [localRoute moToDictionary:localRoute];
    self.tempContext.parentContext = moc; // crashes here
```

Everything is good until I try to set the `parentContext` of my `tempContext` to the main MOC.  I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator;  cannot replace.'
```

I understand it's telling me that I cannot change the `persistentStoreCoordinator`.  However I'm nto sure why it's telling me that.  When I set a breakpoint, the `tempContext` is at a different memory addres than the main moc.  Also, the `self.tempContext.parentContext` is nil.  So I'd think if it's nil, I could set the nil parameter to the moc, but it crashes.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a managed object context, you can

- either set the persistent store coordinator, to get a second independent MOC with the
  same store,
- or set the parent context to get a child MOC,

but not both.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.  I guess in the end, I'd like to take my object that's from my main MOC, and use it in a tempMoc or localMoc.  I'd like to do that since I already have code that uses that approach to throw away the object if the user decides NOT to save it, and save to the main MOC (parentContext) if they decide to do that.  So I wasn't sure how I could regrab an existing object (which the above code does), but then use it with that same parentContext approach, which it sounds like I cannot do?  Is there a better approach? Thanks. Core Data is new to me!

Comment: @Crystal: That sounds as if you need a child context of the parent MOC, so you set the parent context, but not the store coordinator.

Comment: But how do I get the original object from the main MOC when I retrieve it, into the child MOC.  I set the coordinator because I thought that's how I would get the object into a child MOC.

Comment: Passing the objectID and retrieving the object in the child MOC with `objectWithID:routeID` should also work in the parent/child case.

Comment: Since the self.tempContext doesn't have a coordinator at that time though, I get a crash there instead.

Comment: @Crystal: Of course you should set the parent context *before* calling `objectWithID:...`.

Comment: That totally fixed all my problems.  I first added the parentContext between the two objectId calls before reading your message.  I was getting unexpected behavior.  But once I added the call above both objectID calls, everything worked!  Why does it have to be done before both those calls?