# App keeps crashing on save main context into the parent of child context

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm creating chat application, and created background context for insert, update and delete operations, I have set merge policy type for avoid duplication of msgs into database

but problem is when I am set the parent of child context as main context it crashes the app.

My code for creating backgroung context is

```
lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        var managedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
        managedObjectContext.parent = CoreDataStack.shared.getContext()
        return managedObjectContext

    } else {
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)

        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentStoreCoordinator
        managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType
        return managedObjectContext
    }
}()
```

app crashes on line

```
managedObjectContext.parent = CoreDataStack.shared.getContext()
```

below is the error i am getting

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator; cannot replace
```

Please help where I am doing wrong

Comment: could you add the error you are getting ?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Hi sorry i meant if you could edit the question and add the stack trace. so we can see what the issue is. and try and help out

Comment: error is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator;  cannot replace.'"

Comment: I think there is no need to set parent

Comment: have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217339/4056108)